# How can I change the results of a single column of a sql query, within the query itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm running the below SQL query:

```
SELECT
    share_name AS "Server", 
    Capacity, Available,
    ((available * 1.00) / capacity) * 100 as "% Free"
FROM 
    storage_info
WHERE 
    share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.2%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.3%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.4%';
```

Which returns the results of the 'share_name' column as IP addresses, as they are stored in the table.

Is it possible to change what the output of the IP addresses will be, within the query - in the same way that 'AS' changes the name of the column?

Comment: What do you want them changed to?

Comment: Yes it is. But we can't guess how you want to do it. So add some data example and the desired result on your question.

Comment: So for example, changing '192.168.1.1' to 'Server 1' in the output of the query only - not the data itself (if that makes sense).

Comment: [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) Enjoy

Comment: @Tommen If you have the names corresponding to each IP in some table, then you can join it to that and retrieve the name, otherwise you'll need to use `CASE WHEN share_name = '192.168.1.1' THEN 'Server 1' WHEN .....`

Comment: Oh, wait. Given share names of 168.1, 168.2 and 168.3, are you asking how can you make your column names into `Server 1`, `Server 2`, `Server 3`, etc?

Comment: @billinkc Yep, that's what I mean, sorry for the poor explanation

Comment: @Lamak The names I want to use aren't stored anywhere - at which point in the query should I be using the CASE WHEN... statement?

Comment: @Tommen at the point that the current answers show

Comment: They do indeed! I'll try those out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%' THEN 'SERVER 1'
            WHEN share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.2%' THEN 'SERVER 2'
            WHEN share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.3%' THEN 'SERVER 3'
            WHEN share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.4%' THEN 'SERVER 4'
            ELSE share_name END AS "Server",
       Capacity, Available, ((available * 1.00) / capacity) * 100 as "% Free"
FROM storage_info
WHERE share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%'
   OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.2%'
   OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.3%'
   OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.4%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            share_name = '192.168.1.1' 
        THEN 
            'Server 1' 
        ELSE 
            share_name 
    END AS "Server", 
    Capacity, Available,
    ((available * 1.00) / capacity) * 100 as "% Free"
FROM 
    storage_info
WHERE 
    share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.2%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.3%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.4%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH map([IP],[NAME]) AS (
    select
        [IP],[NAME]
    from (values
        ('192.168.1.1','Server1'),
        ('192.168.1.2','Server2')
)
SELECT
    ISNULL(map.name,share_name) AS "Server", 
    Capacity, Available,
    ((available * 1.00) / capacity) * 100 as "% Free"
FROM 
    storage_info
LEFT JOIN map on
    storage_info.share_name = map.IP
WHERE 
    share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.2%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.3%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.4%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the desired output.  Just add a case for each IP you want to output differently.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%' THEN 'Server 1' END AS "Server", 
    Capacity, Available,
    ((available * 1.00) / capacity) * 100 as "% Free"
FROM 
    storage_info
WHERE 
    share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.1%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.2%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.3%'
    OR share_name LIKE '%192.168.1.4%';
```

You probably don't need the leading wildcard on your `WHERE` conditions which will speed this query greatly.